# Eclipse console link for files not in source

Tags: eclipse

I'm writing an application in Java that does some processing on arbitrary .java files.  I'm using Eclipse, and when there's part of a .java file that it doesn't understand, I print out to the System.err stream:

```
System.err.format("Unable to resolve name %s (%s:%d)\n",
                  node.getName(), node.filePath(), node.getStartLine());
```

So it will print out something like this:

> Unable to resolve name Foo (C:\project\src\Project\bar.java:63)

And the Eclipse console puts a link on the path and line part of the error. When I try to click on it, it says:

> Source not found for C

I assume that's because Eclipse is only looking at source files in the project I'm running, not in the arbitrary .java file I'm processing.  Is there any way to make it actually open that file and go to that line?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Unfortunately, the answer is no. Eclipse will only match the files against the resources in the workspace.

Comment: Are there any plugins I can use?

Comment: No, afraid not. In theory, you should be able to write and install your own _linkifier_, but I have never tried this.